# While trying to install and run the program, it shows me the following error

Tags: android, androidx

I've tried copying the same code into a new project and the problem is fixed, but I don't want to create a new project every time this error shows up. is it possible to fix this issue?

Error while Launching activity

> Error while executing: am start -n
>   "com.example.webactivity/com.example.webactivity.MainActivity" -a
>   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.example.webactivity/.MainActivity } Error type 3 Error:
>   Activity class
>   {com.example.webactivity/com.example.webactivity.MainActivity} does
>   not exist.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to the Linear Layout Program"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="Please Enter Your Credentials :"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        />
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Age"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        />
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/rolno"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Roll No."
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        />
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/percent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Percentage"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        />
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/dob"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:hint="DOB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        />
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Insert"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/insert"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/delete"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Display"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:onClick="adisplay"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
    package com.example.webactivity;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AppCompatButton bi,bd,bdi;
    AppCompatEditText n,a,rn,p,dob;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bi=findViewById(R.id.insert);
        bd=findViewById(R.id.delete);
        bdi=findViewById(R.id.display);
        n=findViewById(R.id.name);
        a=findViewById(R.id.age);
        rn=findViewById(R.id.rolno);
        p=findViewById(R.id.percent);
        dob=findViewById(R.id.dob);
    }
    public void adisplay(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, n + "\n" + a + "\n" + rn + "\n" + p + "\n" + dob, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, share some code.

Comment: add manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line in .xml file

```
tools:context=".com.example.webactivity.MainActivity"
```